# How can I console.log the title of a clicked bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I have this popover code:

```
  $('.UofTennesseeKnox').popover({
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': '<a class="passName" href="#">University of Tennessee-Knoxville</a>',
    'content': 'Facilities Services Department 2233 Volunteer Boulevard, Room 203 Knoxville, TN 37996-3010',
    'html': 'true'
  });
```

This code to get the contents of `.passName` doesn't work:

```
        $('.passName').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it not working because `.passName` is in the popover, can I do something like this to get the `$('.passName').click(function())` to fire only after the popover is loaded?:

```
  $('.UofTennesseeKnox').popover({
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': '<a class="passName" href="#">University of Tennessee-Knoxville</a>',
    'content': 'Facilities Services Department 2233 Volunteer Boulevard, Room 203 Knoxville, TN 37996-3010',
    'html': 'true'
  }, passNamefunction());
```

Comment: What's that `passNamefunction()` about as a second argument for `.popover()`? I can't find anything about Bootstrap taking more than one argument for `.popover()` in [the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

Comment: If any of these answers solved your problem you should accept it or let us know if you still have problems so that we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the HTML property `data-original-title` to set the data on your popover element. That way, it's easier for you to read the data later:

```
$(".UofTennesseeKnox").attr("data-original-title", "Your title");
$(".UofTennesseeKnox").popover({ 
    // Your other options here
});

var title = $(".UofTennesseeKnox").attr("data-original-title");
```

I suppose you can even use `.data()` to read the data property later. I didn't verify that.

```
var title = $(".UofTennesseeKnox").data("original-title");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you create this element dinamically, try with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
    $(document).on("click", ".passName", function(){
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
```